# React native Higher Order Component issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Have one problem with HOC.

Basically i have one HOC for rendering 2+ Components

So issue:

I'm passing to children function `onChange` which updates state in HOC. In one view i'm calling this `onChange` function. But when i will go to another view (wrapper with this HOC too) Im not able to see that change.

Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: You need to be more specific with your example: show code and exactly where it breaks, and what does "break" mean in that particular context.

Comment: A proper HOC returns a NEW component class or function. One instance of a component made from a HOC-wrapped class won't know anything about another one made from the same HOC.

Comment: @webdevdani so in that case i can't do anything right? Only if i will wrap them on Top level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @webdevdani pointed out,

> a HOC returns a NEW component class or function

So you will need a parent level component that wraps both of them, or use shared state with something like Redux.

```
class Parent extends Component {
    state = {
        sharedState: ''
    }
    updateState = state => {
        this.setState({
            sharedState: state
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ComponentA updateState={this.updateState} />
                <ComponentB updateState={this.updateState} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class ComponentA extends Component {
    handleChange = () => {
        // this.props.onChange is a prop from the HOC
        this.props.onChange();

        // Here you can also trigger the parent component change handler
        this.props.updateState(...);
    }
    render() {...}
}

export default hoc(ComponentA);

class ComponentB extends Component {
    handleChange = () => {
        // this.props.onChange is a prop from the HOC
        this.props.onChange();

        // Here you can also trigger the parent component change handler
        this.props.updateState(...);
    }
    render() {...}
}

export default hoc(ComponentB);
```